# Wifi raspberry pi 2 problem

Tags: raspbian, wifi

My wifi adapter worked fine with the Rapsberry pi B  but when I update to Raspberry pi2  it doesn't work. I'm using wheezy  and when  I run `lsusb` I get:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

but when  I hit scan  with Wifi-config GUI   nothing appears.

Comment: Try `ip link set wlan0 up` first.

Answer (score 0):

That adapter requires drivers that are not part of the standard raspibian distribution. If you do `ifconfig`, does the interface show up? If not, check [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=62371) for info on getting updated drivers. After you install the driver and reboot, it should show up in `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`. You'll need to do this after every firmware update.

Comment: <this is what a get  when  i run  iwconfig:>/
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any
 Mode:Managed  Ac Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment 
thr:offcess Point: Not- Power Management:off
Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm

Comment: but still no luck when  i hit scan  with wpa-gui

Comment: If it shows up in `iwconfig` the driver is loaded and to some degree working.  I have a RT5370 USB adapter, and it works fine, including on a Pi 2 -- the driver is `rt2x00usb` (you'll see it w/ `lsmod | grep rt2`), which is included in Raspbian.  However, it's not impossible that a bug was introduced in some particular kernel version.

Comment: lsmod | grep rt2
rt2800usb              17886  0 
rt2800lib              71839  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00usb               8517  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              36704  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              479583  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
cfg80211              386516  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
crc_ccitt               1153  1 rt2800lib

Comment: yes i do have the driver  but stil not working

Comment: Have you updated to the current firmware, etc.? `rpi-update` or `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: yes i did  update the firmware but nothing happens

Comment: sudo iwlist wlan0 scan==>
wlan0     No scan results

Answer (score 0):

On my raspberry-pi2 i had the same problem. In the taskbar it seems that the network connection couldn't established, however after I manually entered my wifi SSID and password to /etc/network/interfaces file it was connecting to the internet. So you may try that.